# How can i convert string to only days?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, days

how can I "X years Y months Z days" string convert to only days in Javascript ?
ex:

```
var d="2 years 3 months 12 days";
```

and I must take 832

Comment: Welcome to SO. We ask that coders ask questions about code _they've attempted_ but are having problems with. Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), along with [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to give you the desired output.

We define the intervals we consider along with their names and weights, then use .reduce() to sum the total days in the string.

```js
function getTotalDays(str) {
    let intervals = [ { name: 'year', weight: 365 }, { name: 'month', weight: 30 }, { name: 'day', weight: 1 }];
    return intervals.reduce((acc, { name, weight}) => { 
        let res = new RegExp(`(\\d+)\\s${name}[\\s]?`).exec(str);
        return acc + (res ? res[1] * weight  : 0);
    }, 0);
}

console.log(getTotalDays("2 years 3 months 12 days"))
console.log(getTotalDays("6 months 20 days"))
console.log(getTotalDays("1 year 78 days"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Split the string and convert

```js
const date_str = "2 years 3 months 12 days"
const splitted_str=date_str.split(" ")
const years = parseInt(splitted_str[0])
const months = parseInt(splitted_str[2])
const days = parseInt(splitted_str[4])
const total_days=years*365+months*30+days
console.log(total_days+" days")
```